# The color black

Tags: color

If a perfectly black object were present and it had a rough texture with bumps and crinkles, would it reflect any light? And can black reflect any light?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE.  I think such a question is more appropriate on Physics.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ^

Comment: The perfect black body is called a "black body radiator." It is a theoretical concept which doesn't exist in reality.

Comment: I am closing this as it is [cross-posted to physics.se](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227794).

Answer (score 2):

This question contains a tautology. If we define something as "perfectly black" by definition we mean something that has an absence of color and hence can neither reflect nor emit.

On the other hand, structure on the surface of an object can have a complex effect on the resulting field. For example, much of the coloring in [morpho butterfly wings is due to interference](http://www.asknature.org/strategy/1d00d97a206855365c038d57832ebafa). Other relatively bulk effects exist that can trap light, such as [the reverse laser](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/antilaser-time-reversed/). And obviously a black hole.